# How to output (to a log) a multi-level array in a format that is human-readable?

Tags: php, drupal

I'm working on a drupal site and when debugging, I am always having to read through long, nested arrays. As a result, a large portion of my life is spent using the arrow, return, and tab keys, to split up 1000+ character strings into a nested, readable format.

For drupal devs, I can't use devel's dsm(), as I'm working with multi-step #ahah/#ajax forms, and I can only output the arrays to the error log, not to the screen.

Visual example:

Evil:

```
array ( 'form_wrapper' => array ( '#tree' => true, '#type' => 'fieldset', '#prefix' => '', '#suffix' => '', '#value' => '', 'name' => array ( '#type' => 'textfield', '#title' => NULL, '#size' => 60, '#maxlength' => 60, '#required' => false, '#description' => NULL, '#attributes' => array ( 'placeholder' => 'Email', ), '#post' => array ( 'form_wrapper' => array ( 'name' => '', 'pass' => '', ),
```

...

Good:

```
array ( 
'form_wrapper' => array ( 
    '#tree' => true, 
    '#type' => 'fieldset', 
    '#prefix' => '<div>', 
    '#suffix' => '</div>', 
    '#value' => '', 
    'name' => array ( 
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#title' => NULL, 
        '#size' => 60, 
        '#maxlength' => 60, 
        '#required' => false, 
        '#description' => NULL, 
        '#attributes' => array ( 
            'placeholder' => 'Email', 
        ),
```

**Edit**: Sorry, by "not output to screen", I meant via drupal's system messages where it's possible to output arrays in a clickable, nested format (using devel.module).

Comment: <?php echo '<pre>'.print_r($array,1).'</pre>'; ?>

Answer (score 265, accepted):

If you need to log an error to Apache error log you can try this:

```
error_log( print_r($multidimensionalarray, true) );
```

> If you would like to capture the output of [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), use the return parameter. When this parameter is set to true, print_r() will return the information rather than print it.

Comment: Looks like it's `print_r` (lowercase). Does `print_R` really work as well?

Comment: thanks @AkhilrajNS can you tell me more about how can i send the inserted query or any query which is executed above this log message.?

Comment: @ankitsuthar Did you mean SQL Query ?

Comment: Yes But I got it by the last query function in CI. Actually, I want to log a data which are get inserted or edited, deleted.

Comment: This is dum. This outputs newline characters as literal `\n` instead of actual newlines.

Comment: @Otheus I think may have missed the point in the first sentence. This targets the APACHE ERROR LOG which is a single entry per line. If you want to capture multi-line info it needs to be escaped.

Comment: @oligofren perhaps I missed Akhillaraj's point, but the OP asked for something _human readable_. Apparently this is an apache "security" fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1574558/3849157. But the idea of `print_r` is to output the array in a human-readable way and apache kills that. His is the top answer, mysteriously. Well, maybe things changed since 2013. Or maybe he uses php-fpm or CGI.

Answer (score 23):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php 
This function can be used to format output,

```
$output = print_r($array,1);
```

`$output` is a string variable, it can be logged like every other string. In pure php you can use `trigger_error`

Ex. `trigger_error($output);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php

if you need to format it also in html, you can use `<pre>` tag

Comment: Read the question - OP needs to do this for log output - not screen output.

Comment: @Matt read the answer, `if you need to format it also in html`

Comment: @Fivell, I try. If you clarify your answer to explain that the output can be sent to the log file, I'll remove my -1.

Comment: @Fivell there's a small issue with `trigger_error` it limits messages to max 1024 length or something similar. Making some longer `var_exports`/`print_r` strings get cut-off. It's useful for simple structures.

Answer (score 14):

I just wonder why nobody uses or recommends the way I prefer to debug an array:

```php
error_log(json_encode($array));
```

Next to my browser I `tail` my server log in the console eg.

```sh
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

---

Though it's debatable if the output is human-readable, but it's still my preferred way to read it and would look something like that:

```php
[Tue Dec 13] [...] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: {"form_wrapper":{"#tree":true,
"#type":"fieldset","#prefix":"","#suffix":"","#value":"","name":{"#type":
"textfield","#title":null,"#size":60,"#maxlength":60,"#required":false,
"#description":null,"#attributes":{"placeholder":"Email"},"#post":{
`"form_wrapper":{"name":"","pass":""}}}}}', referer: http://localhost/
```

Comment: Because it's not "human readable" :D 
Seriously, this is a good idea though. A post-processor combined with `jq` can make this an excellent debugging tool

Answer (score 11):

### Simple stuff:

Using `print_r`, `var_dump` or `var_export` should do it pretty nicely if you look at the result in view-source mode not in HTML mode or as @Joel Larson said if you wrap everything in a `<pre>` tag.

`print_r` is best for readability but it doesn't print null/false values.

`var_dump` is best for checking types of values and lengths and null/false values.

`var_export` is simmilar to `var_dump` but it can be used to get the dumped string.

The format returned by any of these is indented correctly in the source code and `var_export` can be used for logging since it can be used to return the dumped string.

### Advanced stuff:

Use the xdebug plug-in for PHP this prints `var_dump`s as HTML formatted strings not as raw dump format and also allows you to supply a custom function you want to use for formatting.

Comment: Read the answer `var_export` allows you to return a string.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal's [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) has other useful functions including ones that can print formatted arrays and objects to log files. See the guide at http://ratatosk.net/drupal/tutorials/debugging-drupal.html

> **dd()**
>
> Logs any variable to a file named “drupal_debug.txt” in the
>   site’s temp directory. All output from this function is appended to
>   the log file, making it easy to see how the contents of a variable
>   change as you modify your code.
>
> If you’re using Mac OS X you can use the Logging Console to monitor
>   the contents of the log file.
>
> If you’re using a flavor of Linux you can use the command “tail -f
>   drupal_debug.txt” to watch the data being logged to the file.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you

<strike>`echo '<pre>';`</strike>

```
$output = print_r($array,1);
```

<strike>`echo '</pre>';`</strike>

**EDIT**

using `echo '<pre>';` is useless, but `var_export($var);` will do the thing which you are expecting.

Comment: @Matt When this parameter is set to TRUE, print_r() will return the information rather than print it.

Answer (score 1):

**Syntax**

```
print_r(variable, return);
```

variable    **Required**. Specifies the variable to return information about

return      **Optional**. When set to true, this function will return the information (not print it). Default is false

**Example**

```
error_log( print_r(<array Variable>, TRUE) );
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>You should be able to use a var_dump() within a pre tag. Otherwise you could look into using  a library like dump_r.php: https://github.com/leeoniya/dump_r.php</del>

My solution is incorrect. OP was looking for a solution formatted with spaces to store in a log file.

A solution might be to use output buffering with var_dump, then str_replace() all the tabs with spaces to format it in the log file.

Comment: Read the question - OP needs to do this for log output - not screen output.

Comment: I did read the question. Missed that last little comment. Thanks for letting me know. This solution is not going to work then.